# Reversing a text read from console

Tags: c++

I'm trying to understand recursive functions and I was trying to make a function that reverses the text read from the console. For example if one inputs "abcd" then the output will be "dcba".

This is what I have (I didn't come up with it myself).

```
void reverse() {
    char c;
    c=getchar();
    if(c!='\n') 
        reverse();
    cout<<c;
}
```

[For testing purposes.](http://cpp.sh/7y4ry)

Most of the issue comes from `if(c!='\n')` (or I thought so until now). Is there an intuitive explanation on how this function works?
And perhaps is there a better way to build the function(recursively)?

Comment: I seem to be missing your question, your test works

Comment: Yes, it does work.. But I don't understand why. I know what '\n' does, but I suspected there's something hidden about it, but perhaps your answer points that the issue is with that getchar function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursive functions use a call stack to store function calls. The last called function goes on top of the call stack (Last-in-First-Out).

Given that your string is "ABCD" the following recursion tree is generated:

- `A` : call `reverse()`
- `B` : call `reverse()`
- `C` : call `reverse()`
- `D` : call `reverse()`
- `\n` : At this point the control of execution passes back to the previous call until the call stack is depleted.

Note that every call to `reverse()` is followed by a pending `cout`, which executes once the control of execution is passed back.
Hence, the characters `DCBA` are printed to the standard output

Comment: Something is still blurry for me, getchar() reads a character from the keyboard right? Since it was inputed "ABCD" it makes  c="A" and by calling reverse() it moves on the stack. But on the second iteration, how does c become "B"?

Comment: The recursion stack includes the values of all variables at every function call. Moving on to a fresh call does not imply the old value is lost or over-written. All values read from the input are stored in order in the stack for every step and traversed back once the control is passed back using the corresponding value at that step.

Comment: Maybe you could read up on this article to have a better idea of how recursions work:

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-recursion-works-explained-with-flowcharts-and-a-video-de61f40cb7f9/

Answer (score 0):

`\n` is the marker for a new line, so all your if statement does is check for a line end, and if it is a line end print out the whole thing.

Comment: Oh, so I wasn't even looking in the right place in order to understand the function..

Comment: No this is where the reversal occurs, but it is possible your getchar function is not returning what is should for this to work.  Because it seems like to me, this itself should work.